# Play 1.2.4: process POST request with XML in the body

Tags: xml, apache-flex, post, jaxb, playframework

I've searched around for docs/examples of processing a POST request with XML as the body but can't seem to find up-to-date examples for play 1.2.4 (there is a nice annotation you can use for play 2.0 though).

I have a Flex app that is posting XML like so:

```
public function post( url:String, xml:XML ):void
{
    var service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
    var responder:Responder = new Responder( postResult, postFault );
    var token:AsyncToken;
    service.method = "POST";
    service.contentType = "application/xml";
    service.resultFormat = "e4x";
    service.url = url;
    token = service.send( xml );
    token.addResponder( responder );
}
```

How can I access the body as XML so I can process it with JAXB?

thanks!

Comment: You can access body of a HTTP POST request with 
**request.body** in controller, note that it's in InputStream type.
Then you could use any XML parser or serializer/deserializer to deal with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two methods that I know of.

1. You can use `request.body`, which returns an InputStream. Probably a little long-winded for people used to simplicity of Play.
2. Simply call `params.get("body")`. This will return the whole of the body.

Clearly you are most likely to want to go with option 2, but for some use cases option 1 may be preferred.